# IF statement is not functioning?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements, comparison-operators

I'm no wizard, but I've been playing around trying to learn a bit with google apps script and I'm just confused as to why it isn't working. I've looked through the documentation and have referenced other works using if + else scripts and I can't find the error.
Context: E7 is a checkbox, F7 is a fill-in-the-blank.

```
function testO() {
  var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getRange = mySS.getRange("E7")
  
  
  if(getRange = true){
    mySS.getRange("E7").setValue("FALSE")
  }
  else{
    mySS.getRange("F7").clearContent()
  }
}
```

Comment: `mySS` is a Spreadsheet object not a Sheet object.  `var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`.  And logical comparison is 'getRange == true'.

Comment: @TheWizEd I'm not sure I fully understand. I know the order is Spreadsheet -> Sheet -> Range -> Cell, so would you mean I need to add a line like:
`var myS = mySS.getSheets()[0];`
I've seen this and have tried it, but when I change the var getRange to myS.getRange it does nothing.

Also, for further clarification, the if statement works fine. If the checkbox is true, it works. However when its false, it doesn't work at all, even if I change it to a else if or another if statement.

Comment: `if(getRange.isChecked()){`

Comment: No `var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` returns the active Sheet.  In your OP your command `var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` returns the active Spreadsheet so `var getRange = mySS.getRange("E7")`  doesn't know what sheet you are refering to.

Comment: @TheWizEd Sorry if it sounds like it, but I don't mean to be argumentative or anything. I just want to make sure I understand. When the code runs, the if true statement works. If the thing is checked, it works, if it's not though, it doesn't. I don't quite understand how the if statement works while the else does not.

Comment: Did you edit your script either as shown in Rueben's or Cooper's answer or if you are still using a Range per TheMaster's comment?

Comment: JavaScript is hard for newbies, learn the concepts operator, expression, truthy and falsy.  Mozilla Developer Network might be a good source just keep focused on the JavaScript part.

Comment: My goto for [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) and for [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

Comment: @TheWizEd It's sort of a mish-mash, but I found Rueben's more helpful overall. Thanks for the help.
`function testO() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  const gR = sh.getRange("Main!E7");
  const v = rg.getValue();

  if(gR.isChecked()){
    gR.uncheck();
  }
  else{
    sh.getRange("Main!F7").clearContent();
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you need to spend some time learning the pretty basics of JavaScript. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets as it gives helpful pointers like,

- Google Apps Script programming language is JavaScript
- How to read and write to a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

Regarding the specifics of your code,

1. (optional) In the `mySs.getRange` methods, instead of `A1` use `Sheet1!A1` style references. This might help to improve the code readability.
2. In the comparison expressions for equality in your if statement, instead of the assign operator `=` use abstract equality `==` or strict equality `===` operators, but in this very specific case it might be better to use `Range.isChecked()`.
3. There are specific methods for working with checkboxes: `Range.isChecked()`, `Range.uncheck()`, `Range.check()`;

Below is a proposal to fix your script:

```
function testO() {
  var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getRange = mySS.getRange("Sheet1!E7");
  
  
  if(getRange.isChecked()){
    getRange.uncheck();
  }
  else{
    mySS.getRange("Sheet1!F7").clearContent();
  }
}
```

Notes:

- Google Apps Script use the same method name for some methods that return the same type of object, i.e. `Spreadsheet.getRange`, `Sheet.getRange`, but they might require different parameters,
- `Spreadsheet.getRange` might use `A1` or `Sheet1!A1` style references. When using `A1` it will get the cell `A1` from the first sheet.
- `Sheet.getRange` might use `A1` style, it will return the cell `A1` from the corresponding sheet, no matter of its position.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example with some explanation

```
function testO() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//I like havign access to the spreadsheet as a single variable.  While it may not be important now it might be in the future.
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//For clerity sake it is better to identify the sheet you are going to.  In your code you depended upon the fact that the spreadsheet has a default active sheet which is ss.getSheets()[0]
  const rg = sh.getRange("E7");//getRange returns a range no a value
  const v = rg.getValue();//getValue returns a single value
  
  if(v == true){ //= is an assignment == is a comparison 
    sh.getRange("E7").setValue("FALSE");//This is usually the value reserved for an unchecked checkbox
  }
  else{
    rg.clearContent()
  }
}
```